# Is the Secret sharing scheme thresholds of variable of interest shared related with the entropy of the variable?

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, entropy, probability

1. Is the $t$ out of $n$, namely $(t,n)$, threshold in the secret sharing scheme related to the entropy of the random variable that is shared according to the scheme?
2. What changes in the secret sharing scheme if $t=n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is the $t$ out of $n$, namely $(t,n)$, threshold in the secret sharing scheme related to the entropy of the random variable that is shared according to the scheme?

No.  You can use a $(t,n)$ sharing scheme (for any $t>0$) to share a value that has one bit of entropy - e.g. everyone knows that it is either a 0 or a 1.  And, even in that case, with $t-1$ shares and that public information, you still don't have any information to determine which it is.

> 2. What changes in the secret sharing scheme if $t=n$?

Nothing changes.

What does change is that you could use a simpler scheme; instead of using something like Shamir's (which involves complicated operations such as inversion or modular division), you can use a simple xor-based scheme; where the first $n-1$ shares are just random values, and the last share is the xor of all the other shares and the secret.  However, that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: you say that "you can use a simple xor-based scheme; where the first n−1 shares are just random values, and the last share is the xor of all the other shares and the secret." Could you give an example of such a multiparty scheme or where to search for this? If there is already an example in the forum you could also mention it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Let $x \in X$ be the secret in some domain $X$, which we'll assume to be byte strings of equal length. Let $s_0, \ldots s_{n-1}$ be the shares. Define  $s_i \leftarrow X, 0 \leq i \leq n - 2$ to be random elements of the domain for the first $n - 1$ shares. Define $s_{n-1} = s_0 \oplus s_1 \ldots \oplus s_{n-2} \oplus x$ to be the last share.
Reconstruction is then trivially the XOR of all shares $s_i$.

Comment: @Morrolan please check this $k$-out-of-$k$ secret-sharing: Select $k-1$ shares, say $s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_{K-1}$ from $D$ and let $s_k=s-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} s_i$ where $s_i$ denotes the $i$-th share.

Comment: $\textbf{Lemma:}$ The above scheme is a k-out-of-k secret-sharing scheme.

Comment: $\textbf{Proof:}$ All shares together obviously determine the secret, hence the set of all $k$ players is qualified. Any set of $k-1$ players, with say $p_i$ missing is ignorant because these $k-1$ shares $(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_{i-1},s_{i+1},\cdots,s_{k})$ are independent and uniformly random, independent of $s$. This follows from the fact that for any fixed $s$ and any fixed missing share $s_i$, the mapping from $(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_{k-1})$ to $(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_{i-1},s_{i+1},\cdots,s_{k})$ is one-to-one. The shares can be simulated by generating a set of uniform and independent shares.

Comment: @Morrolan so in other words does the above lemma means that if you miss one share from the $k$ parts of the shares that are distributed you can not elicit $s$?

Comment: @HungerLearn yes, this scheme looks as if it has information-theoretic security.

Comment: @morrolan i have made a new post where I ask some questions. If you want take a look. And thanks!

Comment: This is the link https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/secure-multi-party-computation-made-simple-questions